# PHP: Populating a multidimensional array whilst checking for duplicates and updating quantities if found

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to improve in a material picking page, where previously every item was displayed without checking for duplicate quantities, so sometimes items will appear multiple times, rather than just changing the quantity.

I thought it would be best to re write the code to populate a multidimensional array and check the array each time for a duplicate.

Here's the code:

```
$get_materials = MySqlDb::query("SELECT * FROM material_item WHERE link_id = '$ids'");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_materials)) {
   if($row['option_1_answers'] == '' && $row['option_2_answers'] == '' &&    $row['option_3_answers'] == '' && $row['option_4_answers'] == '') {

  // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    Relevant section which I need to copy below once correct

   $key = array_search($row['standard'],$comparision_string);
     if($key !== false) {
      $comparision_string[$key]["quantity"] += $row['quantity'];
    }else{
      $comparision_string[$number_count]["description"] = $row['standard'];
      $comparision_string[$number_count]["quantity"] = $row['quantity'];
    }

  //END of relevant section ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


}elseif($row['option_1_answers'] != '' && $row['option_2_answers'] == '' && $row['option_3_answers'] == '' && $row['option_4_answers'] == '') {
  $comparision_string[$number_count]["description"] = $row['standard'] . "[" . $row['option_1_title'] . " = " . $row['option_1_answers'] . "]";
}elseif($row['option_1_answers'] != '' && $row['option_2_answers'] != '' && $row['option_3_answers'] == '' && $row['option_4_answers'] == '') {
  $comparision_string[$number_count]["description"] = $row['standard'] . "[" . $row['option_1_title'] . " = " . $row['option_1_answers'] . "]" . "[" . $row['option_2_title'] . " = " . $row['option_2_answers'] . "]";
}elseif($row['option_1_answers'] != '' && $row['option_2_answers'] != '' && $row['option_3_answers'] != '' && $row['option_4_answers'] == '') {
  $comparision_string[$number_count]["description"] = $row['standard'] . "[" . $row['option_1_title'] . " = " . $row['option_1_answers'] . "]" . "[" . $row['option_2_title'] . " = " . $row['option_2_answers'] . "]" . "[" . $row['option_3_title'] . " = " . $row['option_3_answers'] . "]";
}elseif($row['option_1_answers'] != '' && $row['option_2_answers'] != '' && $row['option_3_answers'] != '' && $row['option_4_answers'] != '') {
  $comparision_string[$number_count]["description"] = $row['standard'] . "[" . $row['option_1_title'] . " = " . $row['option_1_answers'] . "]" . "[" . $row['option_2_title'] . " = " . $row['option_2_answers'] . "]" . "[" . $row['option_3_title'] . " = " . $row['option_3_answers'] . "]". "[" . $row['option_4_title'] . " = " . $row['option_4_answers'] . "]";
}
$comparision_string[$number_count]["quantity"] = $row['quantity'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["collected"] = $row['collected'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["ordered"] = $row['ordered'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["collect_by"] = $row['collect_by'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["order_by"] = $row['order_by'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["datetime_ordered"] = $row['datetime_ordered'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["datetime_collected"] = $row['datetime_collected'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["ids"] = $row['ids'];
$comparision_string[$number_count]["standard"] = $row['standard'];


echo "<tr><td><img src='" . $row['image'] . "'></td><td>" .$comparision_string[$number_count]['quantity'] . " of " . $comparision_string[$number_count]['description'] . "</td><td>";
```

I get a Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

I imagine there is A) A way to make this work and B) A better way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

You are asking `array_search()` to find `$row['standard']` in `$comparision_string` before it is ever declared -- that is never going to work for you.

Furthermore, I can't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Are you counting total answers out of 4 total?  What if answers 2 and 4 are empty?  Your condition block won't catch that.

I don't see any declaration of what `$number_count` is.  Without that, it will permanently 0.

I am highly suspicious that your `$comparision_string[$number_count]["description"]` value assigning process is not going to yield what you intend to get -- but again, I don't really know what you're doing.

I will assume you are sanitizing/validating your `$ids` before it is used in the query.

Yes, I agree with you, there is:

> A) A way to make this work and B) A better way of doing it

but no one can confidently help you with the lack of information about the task you are undertaking.

One last assumption:  If you want to count how many empty values are in the four options_n_answers then you can do something like this:

```
// isolate the four answer elements
$answers_array=array($row['option_1_answers'],$row['option_2_answers'],
                     $row['option_3_answers'],$row['option_4_answers']);
// retain only empty valued elements
$empty_answers_array=array_intersect($answers_array,array(''));
// count the empties
$empty_answer_count=sizeof($empty_answers_array);
// then you can subtract that from sizeof($answers_array) or whatever you need
```